# MaterialComponents show error in xcode 12.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, material-components, material-components-ios

I am using pod 'MaterialComponents/TextControls+OutlinedTextFields' in Xcode 11.3 that is working fine, but same code run in Xcode 12.2 that is so error on

import MaterialComponents.MaterialTextControls_OutlinedTextFields

And the message is >>

No such module MaterialComponents.MaterialTextControls_OutlinedTextFields

Comment: Might need to `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` to force the refresh the Xcode module cache.

Comment: I am trying this, but still show some error.

Comment: clean and run again. If you are running on M1 chip, add arm64 in excluded architecture.

Comment: I added arm64 in excluded architecture and also clean the project several times, Still not able to fix this bug. Please assist, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes facing issues like 'no such module' on m2